# How to convert String to list<object> for a test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have a Json getting it in Aura Controller, and for test class, I am mimicking the Json into a string .

Original

`JSON = [{"subid":"a4wgwe00000DfDRAA0","totalgs":"25","Revenue":"17"},{"subid":"a4wg0000weDfDUAA0","totalgs":"73080","Revenue":"109797"}]`

I wanted to pass the String into `list<object>`** How to do that?

`String a='[{"subid":"a4wgwe00000DfDRAA0","totalgs":"25","Revenue":"17"},{"subid":"a4wg0000weDfDUAA0","totalgs":"73080","Revenue":"109797"}]';`

my method is **submithistory(`list<object>`)**

Tried things

```
String a='[{"subid":"a4wgwe00000DfDRAA0","totalgs":"25","Revenue":"17"},{"subid":"a4wg0000weDfDUAA0","totalgs":"73080","Revenue":"109797"}]';
system.debug((List<object>) System.JSON.deserialize(a));
```

and

```
Map<string,object> obj = (Map<string,object>)json.deserializeUntyped('[{"subid":"a4wgwe00000DfDRAA0","totalgs":"25","Revenue":"17"},{"subid":"a4wg0000weDfDUAA0","totalgs":"73080","Revenue":"109797"}]');

list<object> ob = (list<object>)obj .get('Test');
for(object ooo:ob ){
Map<string,object> o = (Map<string,Object>)ooo ;
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? are you stuck somewhere in your code? please [edit] your post to include this information. thanks

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: and what is the problem? any errors?

Comment: its throwing error .. string to list<object> error so do you think those snippets are correct?? or do you have solutions.

Answer (score 3):

That is `List<Map<String,Object>>`. However, you cannot do type casting directly. You can do it as below:

```
List<object> objList = (List<object>)json.deserializeUntyped('[{"subid":"a4wgwe00000DfDRAA0","totalgs":"25","Revenue":"17"},{"subid":"a4wg0000weDfDUAA0","totalgs":"73080","Revenue":"109797"}]');

for(Object obj : objList){
    Map<String,Object> objRec = (Map<String,Object>)obj;
    String subid = (String)objRec.get('subid');
    System.debug(subid);
}
```

Comment: I have to send it in system.debug(PRDApplicationController.submitForApproval(pr.id, objRec , 1.1, 1.1, false));

Getting Error Sas
`Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void submitForApproval(Id, Map<String,Object>, Decimal, Decimal, Boolean) from the type PRDApplicationController`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `System.JSON.deserialize` you have to specify the type it should deserialize into.

When you specify `List<Object>.class` in the second param, it parses and returns you what you want.

```
String a='[{"subid":"a4wgwe00000DfDRAA0","totalgs":"25","Revenue":"17"},{"subid":"a4wg0000weDfDUAA0","totalgs":"73080","Revenue":"109797"}]';
system.debug((List<object>) System.JSON.deserialize(a , List<Object>.class));
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserialize